# what is the purpose of the following command: choco install chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

In cholocatey gallery, I see the most installed packaged is chocolatey.
what is the purpose of "choco install chocolatey" because obvioulsy this command will run only if chocolatey is already installed ... what am I missing? Is it only kind of an alternative to update it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

As part of a refresh of the Chocolatey website, the `choco install chocolatey` command is no longer shown on the Chocolatey package.  Instead, there is a link to the installation instructions for Chocolatey.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You are right, the command `choco install chocolatey` doesn't actually make any sense.  You need to install Chocolatey using the [instructions](https://chocolatey.org/install) on the site.

However, Chocolatey itself is actually shipped as a Chocolatey package, hosted on chocolatey.org, so once you have it installed, it is possible to use the command `choco upgrade chocolatey` and it will download and install the latest version.

The command `choco install chocolatey` appearing on the site is just a side effect of it shipping as a Chocolatey package.  There is currently a re-write of chocolatey.org happening, and I believe that this particular side effect is being fixed, so that you won't see this on the site anymore.